What did Bertrand Russell mean when talking about the natural law argument for God?
I am trying to understand a particular passage within Why I Am Not A Christian by Bertrand Russell and I had 3 (related) questions (which I hope is fine here). He writes:

natural laws are a description of how things do in fact behave, and being a mere description of what they in fact do, you cannot argue that there must be somebody who told them to do that, because even supposing that there were you are then faced with the question, ‘Why did God issue just those natural laws and no others?’ If you say that He did it simply from His own good pleasure, and without any reason, you then find that there is something which is not subject to law, and so your train of natural law is interrupted. If you say, as more orthodox theologians do, that in all the laws which God issues He had a reason for giving those laws rather than others—the reason, of course, being to create the best universe, although you would never think it to look at it—if there was a reason for the laws which God gave, then God Himself was subject to law, and therefore you do not get any advantage by introducing God as an intermediary. You have really a law outside and anterior to the divine edicts, and God does not serve your purpose, because He is not the ultimate lawgiver. In short, this whole argument about natural law no longer has anything like the strength that it used to have.

Referring to the first part, he says that if laws are just descriptions, you cannot argue that there must be somebody who told them to do that. But even if they weren’t just descriptions, and actual prescriptions controlling reality, why does that imply somebody told them to do that?
Secondly, correct me if I’m wrong, it seems that he says if God chose to establish these laws instead of another without any further reason, then this means His “choice” was not made through a law. If this is correct, then what is the problem here? As far as I know, many theists usually claim that laws hold within the universe, not that laws themselves were decided by other laws or that God is subject to law.
Lastly, is his final point that if God decided these laws based on further reason, then in a way He is subject to something else that is anterior to or outside Him, and thus there is no explanatory benefit in positing Him?

law=simple regularity, no legislator. law=act of legislation imposed to "inert" reality, the there is a legislator that voluntarly acts.

@MauroALLEGRANZA by using the term “legislation” you are already assuming that someone wrote it. The question is why assume that a law, even if prescriptive, implies a law giver?

law=imposed to  god by some "outer" necessity, then there is a super-law to which god is subject, and thus a furter legislator is needed. Law=free choice of god, then this fact is inexplicable from a "rational" point of view and thus outside human research abou laws of nature.

Is it true? Maybe, maybe not. For sure, the uselessness of the concept in god in science is well understood since Galileo time.

Regarding question 3, it's very similar to the Euthyphro dilemma

It's a kind of Euthryphro Dilemma
If something is good, such as helping old ladies across the street and being nice to children, just because God commanded it, and for no other reason, then it's essentially arbitrary. God could just as easily have commanded something completely different. So what is claimed to be law, is not really law-like.
On the other hand, if there are actually good reasons for helping old ladies across the street etc, and they are good not just because God commanded it but for some other reason, then God becomes ethically irrelevant. We don't need to know that God commanded it, we just need to know what that reason was. God turns out to be subjected to some higher law than Himself.

Whether it's relevant to Mr. Russel's argument or not I can't say, but the picture of a God who is limited in various including logical consistency (not able to create square circles etc) does seem consistent with Judaism and Christianity.
